# Are all these Cocoapod files supposed to be red after installing?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, cocoapods

I just started a new project from scratch and tried to install Parse with Cocoapods for the first time. I'm using Xcode 6.4 and Cocoapods 0.37.2.

I did the standard Cocoapods install with Terminal:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod setup --verbose

cd ~/Documents/"Application Development"/VeilApp
pod init
open -a Xcode Podfile
```

In my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'VeilApp' do

pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseUI'

end

target 'VeilAppTests' do

end
```

And then again in Terminal:

```
pod install
```

I closed xcodeproj and opened xcworkspace version of app, and then I run into this:

imgur.com/D272Tle

Basically a bunch of red (not found? not linked correctly?) Cocoapod files. I tried to save something on Parse, and it does work. But then I tried to subclass PFQueryTableViewController and it couldn't find it. I'm not exactly sure where I went wrong, did I skip a step in installing Cocoapods? I'm quite new to programming in general, so if someone could shed a light on what I'm doing wrong it would be awesome if it comes with steps :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short Answer = yes

**red** items in `Frameworks` and `Products`, pointing to *derived data* are normal.
[image: Red items in Pods]

---

## Troubleshooting

Have you tried the obvious:

1. Quit/Relaunch Xcode
2. Xcode > Window > Projects >  Derived Data **Delete...**
3. Proper `import ParseUI` in your Swift source code
4. Start over: `rm -rf Podfile.lock Pods/ ; pod install`

Assuming you got this after the `pod install`:

```
Downloading dependencies
Installing Bolts (1.2.0)
Installing Parse (1.7.5)
Installing ParseUI (1.1.4)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

...and you followed Cocoapod's advice (generally better to have closed Xcode Project before creating the workspace)...

> [!] From now on use `VeilApp.xcworkspace`.

...then this does work:

## Swift

```
import ParseUI

class MyQueryTableViewController : PFQueryTableViewController {
}

class AClass {
    func aFunction() {
        let pf:PFQueryTableViewController = MyQueryTableViewController(style: .Plain)
    }
}
```

Comment: The red items are still there, but it does work now. Thank you so much for this! I think the main problem was I didn't import ParseUI, I mistakenly thought that importing Parse was enough for all of its functionality.