# Framework file is always red in iOS Swift Framework Project

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I'm trying to build an iOS framework, I did this by going to File -> New Project -> Cocoa Touch Framework.

However, I never was able to locate the .framework file event if I successfully build the project, it is always displayed in red and it's not there when I open the project's files in Finder, here is a screenshot:

[image]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Choose "Build Only Device -> Generic iOS device" should work

[image: Screenshot 1]

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer** = yes

red items in `Frameworks` and `Products`, pointing to *derived data* are normal.

---

See this related response:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31226316/218152